# how i can optimize performance of this mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mariadb

I want to optimize performance of this MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%leo%') UNION 
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%le%') UNION
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%eo%') UNION
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%l%') UNION
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%e%') UNION
  (SELECT * FROM users USE INDEX(names) WHERE name LIKE '%o%')
) as A LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

I want values sorted like this (leo, le, eo, l, e, o)

Comment: The condition `LIKE '%something%'` can't be optimized with an index. The `%` at the beginning prevents the index from being useful.

Comment: Thank you, if i will use =, how i can optimize it.

Comment: Those `LIKEs` imply that your names might nave many more letters.  For example "oleomargarine" would match all of the subqueries.  If you have only short words, say so; the solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really optimize the `LIKE` condition if it begins with `%`. Indexes are B-trees, so the search string has to match the beginning of the value in order to narrow it down with an index.

You can use `OR` the combine all the `LIKE` conditions in the `WHERE` clause, and then put each condition in the `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name LIKE '%leo%' OR name LIKE '%le%' OR name LIKE '%eo%' OR 
    name LIKE '%l%' OR name LIKE '%e%' OR name LIKE '%o%'
ORDER BY name LIKE '%leo%' DESC, name LIKE '%le%' DESC, name LIKE '%eo%' DESC, 
    name LIKE '%l%' DESC, name LIKE '%e%' DESC, name LIKE '%o%' DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

If you can change from `LIKE` to `=` then you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name in ('leo', 'le', 'eo', 'l', 'e', 'o')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'leo', 'le', 'eo', 'l', 'e', 'o')
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

Comment: adding pos prevents duplicate removal; if there's one row with leo it will now appear 5 times.  you could `order by name like '%leo%' desc, name like '%le%' desc, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are just substrings in [possibly] longer names, this is the fastest because the `WHERE` clause is faster than the other suggestions.

```
SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE name REGEXP "[leo]"
    ORDER BY name LIKE '%leo%' DESC,
             name LIKE '%le%' DESC,
             name LIKE '%eo%' DESC, 
             name LIKE '%l%' DESC,
             name LIKE '%e%' DESC,
             name LIKE '%o%' DESC;
```

`LIKE` is faster than `REGEXP` for equivalent tests.  Alas, the `ORDER BY` cannot be optimized.